# SSRS duplicates parent group id in CSV export

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple SSRS report which shows id, description and credits.

I grouped the report by id and it when it runs it shows id, description and credits. But my end user doesn't want description and credits to show up when they export into CSV.

So i set the Data Element Output for the detail group (description and credits) to NoOutput. Now when I run the report, I only get the id but it is duplicated as many times as there is data for description and credits. So instead of 6 rows showing me only the unique ids, I get around 18 rows consisting of the 6 ids.

I only want the unique 6 ids to show up, please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create two separate tablix. Both with different visibility settings. One will show up when you run the report, the other will show up when you export the report. The expressions will look something like the following.

For the first tablix that will only show when you run the report:

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV"
```

For the second tablix that will only show in the exported CSV file:

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name <> "CSV"
```

Then, in the second tablix, you can just create one column (ID) and a single group to group on the ID column. You can leave your first tablix the way it is.